# Fan-Out Calculation on LTSpice

Tags: ltspice, ttl, schmitt-trigger, nand

I need to find the fan-out of the circuit below. This is a Schmitt Trigger TTL NAND Gate. How can I exactly find the fan-out of the given circuit using LTSpice or calculate it theoretically?

[image: schematic]

[image: signals]

Comment: Just keep loading it with the equivalent input impedance of a typical gate and count the number of gates it takes to make the output voltages not reach the required TTL levels. It won't be good looking at your model circuit.

Comment: You need to begin by defining what you mean by "fan out". This will probably require that you define Voh and Vol. You may also need to determine your "worst case" conditions.

Comment: The input of the gate is a 4k and a diode, in series, while the output is simply `Q5+Q6` -- consider those as the source and the loads. No need to encumber the simulation. BTW, those rise/fall times are exaggerated: you can make them about 1000x less than the period (say `1u`) and you won't be wrong. And the same thinking can be applied if you mean to expand the circuit into its small signal equivalent, for theoretical calculations.

Comment: Boffin, the TTL spec is [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nTMfw.png). Look over the terms there and think about the TTL totem pole arrangement you show in your schematic. You should be have enough information and supporting analysis from theory to match all this up well. Have you tried? It's really not that hard to develop.